# Pluralization of tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tagging

All tags describing categories of words or sentences are pluralized *expressions*, *conjonctions*, *pronoms*, *verbes*, *noms*, *questions*, etc.

Adding the tag *interjections* on some question, I got stuck on this message:

> Creating the new tag [interjections] is not allowed since the tag [interjection] already exists. If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.

This was an unexpected exception. Can we turn it to a plural?

Answer (score 3):

It's done.

---

Voilà, c'est réglé !